# Prevent interface implementation outside the module

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I have an interfaces and theirs implementations:

In module A I have:

```
interface A {
/// Some methods and variables
}

final class ImplA: A {
/// Some methods and variables
}
```

In module B I have:

```
interface B: A {
/// Some methods and variables
}

final class ImplB: B {
/// Some methods and variables
}
```

What kind of trick I could use that in module C it is **not** allowed to do:

```
final class NotAllowedImplA: A {
/// Some methods and variables
}

final class NotAllowedImplB: B {
/// Some methods and variables
}
```

I was thinking about changing interfaces to abstract classes with internal constructor, but then  inheritance for B won't be possible. Other option would be to create a super interface for A and B which have some classes with tricks with internal constructor, but I am not sure if it is possible and how to do that.

If it is not possible to do that then at least for **NotAllowedImplA** compiler should require @OptIn or implementing **NotAllowedImplA** should throw runtime error.

I tried to:

```
abstract class A private constructor() {
/// Some methods and variables
}

final class ImplA: A() {
/// Some methods and variables
}
```

In module B I have:

```
abstract class B private constructor(): A() {
/// Some methods and variables
}

final class ImplB: B() {
/// Some methods and variables
}
```

but there is a compilation error for A() outside module A.

Comment: I would say sealed interfaces, but it restricts the interface from being implemented outside module A.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The whole point of interfaces is to be implemented. What's wrong with things in module C being able to implement the interface? Why is that problematic?

Comment: The module A has a factory for As and the module B has a factory for Bs. A, B are part of SDK. C is part of Application so shouldn't need to be changed if not needed, but it is possible that someone will implement A or B in Application. Then with any changes to SDK, application will get a compilation error.

Comment: Should the SDK be only dealing with the concrete implementations of `A` and `B` (so `ImplA` and `ImplB` here), if passing something different to them causes problems?